Forwarding port 80 to any other port on other machine/IP
Long story short - I have stubborn ISP that blocks ports 80 and 443 on NAT port forwarding. I have private public IP and my server is exposed to the Internet - for example I can setup Minecraft server and it works fine. I also do have several hosting, VPS solutions and domains bought in various providers (regional).
I've been looking for some way of forwarding traffic from one of my domains on port 80 to my local/home server running on some other port like 8080 without necessity of specifying port in the browser.
My question is how - it seems doable, however I could not find satisfying answer to my question on the Internet so far. Maybe I am asking/searching wrong keywords :P I've found a way to setup reverse proxy on same IP, however I do need to forward traffic to entirely other machine with different IP.

You are looking for a reverse proxy.

Yes @vidarlo I thought so, however can you provide any sources of setting it up to external IP? I was looking for a while and cannot find anything substantial. Also how do you handle HTTPS? Same way?

There's no difference if the IP is localhost or external. And yes, both apache and nginx supports reverse proxy with TLS termination. I would suggest reading the documentation.

So be it - thank you for pointing me into right direction :)
